# Trying to make this code that looks inside a open Excel sheet, finds the item inside the folder and copies to a new folder work

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to modify this code to work such as that if there are more than one PDFs in one Excel manifest it puts them together in a new folder rather than into new separate folders. I've been researching for a while and I can't seem to find my specific issue, so I am trying to get this to work for one or more pdfs, if there's more than one it  puts them together and the folder name should be the excel sheets parent folder name.

Edit (Is this enough info? let me know):
Edit 2: Moved the "copy excel sheet section outside of loop"

Column A will have something like this, it might have one or more PDFs listed, the code matches these to the PDFs in the folder and copies them to a new folder. It uses the pdf name for the folder created but I need it to use the parent folder name instead

When the Excel sheet is like this, i need the code to throw all these PDFs in one folder instead of making one folder per row

```
|A|
|--------------|
|1 file name
|2 DocName_abc12345-1234-1234-1234-abdce1234567_1234567_123456.PDF
|3 DocName_abc12345-1234-1234-1234-abdce1234567_1234567_123456.PDF
|4 DocName_abc12345-1234-1234-1234-abdce1234567_1234567_123456.PDF
|5 DocName_abc12345-1234-1234-1234-abdce1234567_1234567_123456.PDF
```

```vb
   Sub MatchFilesAndCopy()
    Dim srcPath As String
    Dim destPath As String
    Dim srcFolder As Object
    Dim srcFile As Object
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim newFolder As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Update the source and destination paths
    srcPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    destPath = "Z:\Team_WIP\Joe\VBATEST\RESULTS\"

    Set srcFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(srcPath)
    
    ' Use the first sheet in the workbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Debug.Print "Source Path: " & srcPath
    Debug.Print "Destination Path: " & destPath

    For Each srcFile In srcFolder.Files
        Debug.Print "Processing File: " & srcFile.Name
        If UCase(Right(srcFile.Name, 3)) = "PDF" Or UCase(Right(srcFile.Name, 3)) = "CSV" Then
            For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                cellValue = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                If cellValue = Left(srcFile.Name, Len(cellValue)) Then
                    newFolder = destPath & cellValue
                    Debug.Print "Processing File: " & srcFile.Name
                    Debug.Print "Checking Cell Value: " & cellValue
                    Debug.Print "New Folder: " & newFolder
                    MkDir newFolder
                    Debug.Print "Folder created: " & newFolder
                    FileCopy srcFile.Path, newFolder & "\" & srcFile.Name 
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next srcFile

' Add code to copy the Excel sheet into the folder with the original file name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newFolder & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

End Sub
```

PDFs and Excel sheet go into the right folder

Comment: It would help if you provided some sample data: examples of file names in your "source" folder, and examples of what data is in column A of your worksheet, and what the expected result would be given that data. Make sure to include an example of two or more files that should go into the same folder, and maybe one or two that do not. You should also define "an Excel manifest" since you mention this in your question.

Comment: there are many questions:
Why do you copy your workbook always in the loop?
And where do you want to copy it when changing the newFolder to parent of workbook. You may first check the logic.
What shall happen if there is only one file - still to the parent folder?